# Выведите на экран таблицу символов и соответствующих им целых чисел

Tags: c++, циклы, while

Буду очень признателен, если поможет разобраться с этой задачей.

Текст задачи: 
Символ `'b'` равен `char('a' + 1)`, `'c'` - равен `char('a' + 2)` и т.д. Используя цикл `while`, выведите на экран таблицу символов и соответствующих им целых чисел.

**a 97

b 98

...

z 122**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char c = 'a' - 1;
while (++c <= 'z'){
    std::cout << int(c) << ' ' << c << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

а что тут помогать?

1. все буквы и символы в памяти
       хранятся в виде чисел.
2. соответствие между числом и буквой
       называется "кодировка"
3. если выводишь как символ получаешь
       символ, если как число то и получишь
       число.

про привидение типов уже читал?

Answer (score 0):

```
char alfavit = '#';
while (++alfavit <= 'z')    {
    cout << int(alfavit) << '\t' << alfavit << endl;
}
```

Можно присвоить символьной переменной значение любого символа(в данном случае #) и инкременировать переменную, пока она не будет равной символу 'z'. Потом просто вывесть переменную в виде числовом(int) и исходном.